# Date formatting using moment in react.js

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I have a date in a format below coming from the database. Using react moment, I will like to 
convert the date to a format like this Sept-10-2018

```
        2018-10-03T05:00:00.000+0000
```

I already added the import line below

```
        import moment from 'moment'
```

How can I achieve this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a moment object by passing your string, then use the [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) method.

```js
const date = moment('2018-10-03T05:00:00.000+0000');

console.log(date.format('MMM-DD-YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.js"></script>
```